# Difference between Kite SDK dataset and Hive Table

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, sqoop, sqoop2

I was reading the documentation of Kite SDK. I'm not able to understand difference between Kite dataset and Hive table

For example, if you want to create the products dataset in Hive, you can use this URI.

`dataset:hive:products`

Does this means, using hive cli we can access the same table `products`

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between a dataset created by the Kite SDK and the table that is viewed through the hive cli.  The reason that is true is because when you use Kite SDK to create a dataset in Hive, what you are creating is a table in Hive.  The confusion lies in the terminology.  What the Kite documentation refers to as a dataset is called a table in Hive.

From the Kite SDK page called "Dataset, View, and Repository URIs" (http://kitesdk.org/docs/1.1.0/URIs.html), the URI format for importing data to a Hive table is as follows.

```
dataset:hive:<namespace>/<dataset>
```

`<namespace>` is equivalent to the database name. Note if left blank, Kite assumes the default database.

`<dataset>` is equivalent to the table name.

**Equivalent commands:**

From OS terminal:

```
#./kite-dataset show tv_shows/sitcoms
```

From hive > terminal:

```
hive> select * from tv_show.sitcoms;
```